# How to parse the JSON data in flume httpSource

Tags: flume-ng

I want to parse the data which is coming to flume httpsource, and extract some content and put it into channel ,.. can anyone help me to write java code to parse the data at flume http source

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors are simple pluggable components that sit between a source and the channel(s) it writes to. Events received by sources can be transformed or dropped by interceptors before they are written to the corresponding channels

The regex filtering interceptor can be used to filter events passing through it. The filtering is based on a regular expression (regex) supplied in the configuration. Each regex filtering interceptor converts the event’s body into a UTF-8 string and matches that string against the regex provided.